# container optimized os ssh timeout too fast

Tags: ssh, google-container-optimized-os

how to fix GCP container optimized os ssh timeout too soon

its `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` has:

```
# Google Compute Engine times out connections after 10 minutes of inactivity.
# Keep alive ssh connections by sending a packet every 7 minutes.
ServerAliveInterval 420
```

but it close connection when idle for around 3 mins

```
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
```

Plus:
its /etc/ is not stateful, which means what ever you change will be wipe out after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

for MacOS set `ServerAliveInterval 120` in client's ~/.ssh/config

```
Host container_optimized_os
  ServerAliveInterval 120
  HostName ipaddr
  Port 22
  User username
  AddKeysToAgent yes
```